# How to read numbers to the end of the file?

Tags: c, do-while

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf, scanf definitions //
#include <math.h>       // sqrt function //


int main(void)
{
    double number;      // input- a number of a set //
    double avg;         // output - average //
    double sdev;        // output - standard deviation //
    double numSq;       // output - input squred //

    int count = 0;      // number of numbers counter //
    int status;         // status of scanf function //
    avg = 0;
    numSq = 0;

    do{
        status = scanf("%lf", &number);

        // Testing Purposes //
       // printf("%f\n", number);

        if (status == 1 && number !=EOF)
        {
            if ( number >=0)
            {

            avg += number;
            numSq += number * number;
            count +=1;
            }
            else if( number <0)
            {
                avg -= number;
                numSq += (number * number);
                count +=1;
            }
        }
        // Make an else for negative numbers and if scanf fails //
       }
       while (number !=EOF );

       avg = avg / count;
       numSq = numSq / count;  
       sdev = sqrt(numSq - (avg * avg));

       printf("The average is %.4f \n", avg);
       printf("The standard deviation is %.4f \n", sdev);

       return 0;
}
```

I also have a text file called `data.txt` that contains:

```
1.0
1.2 
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```

After program compilation, I run:
`./standard < data.txt > results.txt` 
Yet nothing happens! A blank terminal with a flashing dot as this picture shows:

My guess is that the program is stuck in the loop, but why? And how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons between `number` and `EOF` don't make sense, [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) will not set `number` to any specific value if the end of file is reached. Instead, it will *return* `EOF`.

So what you should be testing to determine the end of file is `status == EOF`.

In fact, you should probably break out of the loop if `status != 1` since that would mean either end of file, or invalid input was provided. Try and do proper error reporting in the latter case.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you get rid of the first test (in the if) and change the second (while).

Answer (score 2):

1.We can find out the location end of file but can not retrieve the value of end of file.
2.We can use the return status of scanf family of function.In your case we should run the loop status!=-1.
3.we can read the input of redirected file using scanf.
4.following codes may help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf, scanf definitions //
#include <math.h>       // sqrt function //


int main(void)
{
    double number=0;      // input- a number of a set //
    double avg;         // output - average //
    double sdev;        // output - standard deviation //
    double numSq;       // output - input squred //

    int count = 0;      // number of numbers counter //
    int status;         // status of scanf function //
    avg = 0;
    numSq = 0;
        FILE *fp=NULL;
        fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    do{
        //status = scanf("%lf", &number);
        status=fscanf(fp,"%lf", &number);
        printf("status:%d number:%lf\n",status,number);
        sleep(1);

        // Testing Purposes //
       // printf("%f\n", number);

        if (status == 1 && number !=EOF)
        {
            if ( number >=0)
            {

 avg += number;
            numSq += number * number;
            count +=1;
            }
            else if( number <0)
            {
                avg -= number;
                numSq += (number * number);
                count +=1;
            }
        }
        // Make an else for negative numbers and if scanf fails //
       }
       while (status !=-1 );
        avg = avg / count;
       numSq = numSq / count;
       sdev = sqrt(numSq - (avg * avg));

       printf("The average is %.4f \n", avg);
       printf("The standard deviation is %.4f \n", sdev);

       return 0;
}
```